# Does it make sense to specify a repeated effect that does not appear in the model?

Tags: repeated-measures, random-effects-model, sas

The concentration of a certain nutrient is measured in soil each fall after harvest in a set of research plots.  I want to model the change in nutrient concentration over a number of years, but I'm inclined to express the time variable in days since the start of the study, as the number of days between measurements is not constant.

Here's the SAS code of my present approach:

```
PROC MIXED DATA = soil;
  CLASS year plot;
  MODEL concentration = daysIntoStudy / DDFM = kr;
  REPEATED year / SUB = plot TYPE = ar(1) r;
RUN;
```

I want to indicate an autoregressive covariance structure for the residuals as the same plots are being sampled each year, and I know that the repeated effect must be categorical, but I'm not sure if this is the right way to do it given that the variable *year* does not explicitly appear in the model.

Is this correct?  Also, should the predictor *daysIntoStudy* be specified as a random effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "year" in your repeated statement is a position variable. Suppose you have four year data, as 1,2,3 and 4 in variable year. If you do not specify the "year", SAS will order the obs as they appear in the dataset. Maybe it is not what you want, especially when AR(1) structure is used. Of course, you can sort by plot and year and make obs into correct order.

Another situation is missing data. Suppose for  plot 2, you have data for year 1, 2, and 4, and year 3 is missing. Then SAS will treat it as 1,2,3.

Another method is adding missing values. In the example above, you can add an obs with plot = 2 and year = 3 and other variable are missing. In this way, you will get a dataset with P*Y obs, where P is # of plots and Y is the # of years in your original dataset. Then you do not need year after repeated.

So the variable after REPEATED has no relation with variables in MODEL.

About the correction of your program, it is hard to make the judgement, because you did not give the math model. The function of the program is to tell computer what you want. Here I do not know what you want, of course, I can not say if you tell the computer correctly. If you can give me math model, I can tell you if you Program is correct of not.

You can find more description on SAS manual.